# Method to Pull All Child Objects is Updating Child Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I have a Project model, that can have itself as sub-projects defined as Project.projects.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent_project, class_name: 'Project', optional: true
  has_many :projects, foreign_key: :parent_project_id, class_name: 'Project', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :goals
end
```

Each Project has_many Goals.

I am trying to write a method in the Project model that will enable me to gather all of the goals of this project and it's children projects (recursively) for all sub-projects.

```
  def descendant_projects
    self.projects | self.projects.map(&:descendant_projects).flatten
  end

  def goals_including_descendants
    all_goals = self.goals
    descendant_projects.each do |project|
      all_goals.concat(project.goals)
    end
    all_goals
  end
```

When I call project.goals_including_descendants, the project_id for the children's projects are getting updated in the database to be direct goals of the original parent project. What part of this code would be causing rails to trigger a database update? I can see it in my console as:

```
  Goal Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "goals".* FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 49]]
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "goals" SET "project_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "goals"."id" = $3  [["project_id", 1], ["updated_at", "2020-05-14 20:47:47.761861"], ["id", 19]]
```

I am totally stumped as to why this is happening. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `concat` adds the items to the `self.goals` AR Relation object and updates it immediately.

You could get around this by casting it to an array.

```
all_goals = self.goals.to_a

descendant_projects.each do |project|
  all_goals << project.goals.to_a
end

all_goals.flatten
```

which will return an array in the end, which may or may not be what you're looking for.

Another way would be to get all the ids. This will return a Relation/Enumerable in the end.

```
all_goals_ids = self.goals.ids

descendant_projects.each do |project|
  all_goals_ids << project.goals.ids
end

Goal.where(id: all_goals_ids)
```

Comment: @jfredson Good to hear